# microsoft excel 2010 summary table issues

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have columns of data that have repeating values in one column (see below).

How do I create a summary view (pivot or otherwise) that will have for product 1234 a total billing of 2,000 but total contract value of 12,000.

If I put this into a pivot table, it will add the total contract field to make it 24,000.

```
product  bill date     billing    total contract
1234     jan16      1000.00        12,000
1234     feb16      1000.00        12,000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the pivot table as follow:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question.   Unfortunately, the list that I have has 30,000 lines, so it would be hard to put the total contract across.

Comment: switch the colums with rows